# Is it appropriate to use short form of "have" ('ve) when it means possession?

Tags: verbs, contractions, auxiliary-verbs

I feel uncomfortable saying sentences like the following:

- "**I've** a car" instead of "**I have** a car"
- "**They've** a great time" instead of "**They have** a great time"
- "**He's** a pen" instead of "**He has** a pen"
- etc

I ask this because I read this sort of thing in a book.

Are they correct? And what is the rule? Can you use such forms in a formal setting?

Comment: @serg555: Would you expect anything less on a site for grammar enthusiasts!?

Comment: I think both of them are correct

Comment: I've a car sounds British.

Comment: `He's a pen`, sounds more like `He is a pen`.

Comment: Hmm. So **We've a long way to go** in the UK, before we reach US linguistic standards? I know Americans favour inserting *got* there, but is that a closely-observed rule?

Comment: @JoeD, Well, depends on context and the aural tone used by the speaker.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, ? What were you talking about?

Comment: @Pacerier: I was simply making the point (with a lame attempt at humorously conflating [use/mention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction)) that *We've a long way to go* is (still?) a perfectly valid usage in BrE. You're apparently sceptical of Nohat's assertion that *you can't contract "have" if you are using it as a plain verb (in AmE)*, which I've no reason to question myself. Four years ago I probably thought my usage was a "plain verb" that should be "acceptable" in AmE, but looking at it again now I think it's more of an "auxiliary verb" usage anyway.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To an American ear, it sounds awkward, but in British English, this is not uncommon.  Ironically, a Brit will probably tell you that the correct form is "I have *got* a small dog".

Comment: So the speakers in America don't use "I have *got* a small dog" at all?

Comment: @Marty: Generally, no, I'd say. You're much more likely to hear either "I have a small dog" (which is what's regarded as "correct") or "I've got a small dog".

Comment: I've never heard `I've` used this way, and I've been trying to notice this sort of thing since I moved to London. I've heard `I've got` many times though and I'd regard that as "correct".

Comment: @configurator: It might actually be more of a written thing. Newspapers and such use it quite a bit.  In speech, when you talk about what you have, you probably often use a bit of emphasis somewhere, so the contraction doesn't come into play very clearly.

Comment: Americans say *I’ve got* all the time. Here are some things Americans *have got*: *a secret*; *your back*; *[skills](http://www.goarmy.com/home/skills.html#/?video=63ded117-98f0-46fb-8664-7da29b8b8136&page=0)*;  *[the power](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BRv9wGf5pk)*.

Comment: "Have got" and "'ve got" are very common in America. And incorrect, IMO. Consider the poster child of bad grammar in movie titles, set in New York City: [You've Got Mail](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0128853/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), whose title is, ironically, borrowed from a popular dialog box from *America* Online.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut, Is *"I have got a small dog"* is valid and fully grammatical?

Comment: @Flimzy Why do you call 'have got' incorrect?

Comment: @Flimzy No, 'got' is a past tense of 'get', which mean 'acquire' or obtain - whereas 'have' means 'possess'. For 'to have acquired' to shift to 'to possess' is a perfectly reasonable (and old, having been used by Shakespeare) change.

Comment: As a Brit, I'd say that "I have got a small dog" would almost always be contracted to "I've got a small dog" unless emphasis were needed. Or you were playing Jeeves (and I'm not so sure even _he_'d say that).

Comment: @Flimzy Isn't it just present perfect?

Answer (score 28):

This is definitely an American English/British English thing, as you can't do it in American English but you can in British English.

In American English, you can't contract "have" if you are using it as a plain (not a "helping" or "auxiliary") verb. "I've a dog" and "They've a great time" are not grammatical in American English.

There are a number of other restrictions on contractions of "have" besides the one you cite. For example, you can't use contracted "have" followed by "not": "I've not been there" is not grammatical in American English even though "I've been there" is—if you want to contract, you have to say "I haven't been there".

I [discussed this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50/ivent-a-clue-if-this-is-possible-can-a-word-be-contracted-twice/51#51) in a question about *I’ven’t*.

Comment: Hm, I don't quite see [where's the authority](http://xkcd.com/285) behind the assertion in this answer.

Comment: Also, I'm an American English speaker and I use "I've not" in conversation...

Answer (score 16):

I think what you feel uncomfortable with is contraction of "have" as a main verb. When it's an auxiliary verb in, say, a perfect, contraction feels fine:

> I've had a car before.

But contraction of main verb "have" meaning to own or possess feels weirder.

> ?And I've a car right now.

However, I have a feeling that people will contract main verb have in British English, but take that with a grain of salt. Americans faced with some kind of strange usage are far too willing to blame it on British English.

Comment: You are correct this is a British English thing. Contraction of non-auxiliary *have* is possible in British English but not in American English.

Comment: @nohat: agreed - though only in some regions (as a former Londoner, I would never use "I've" in that context). You also see it in older literature.

Comment: In my neck of the woods, a parent might well say **I've a few things to say to you, young lady!** to an to a recalcitrant teenage daughter.

Answer (score 7):

I think "I've a car" is fine, but unusual on its own: as part of a longer sentence it's unexceptionable: "I've a car in the garage".

I suspect this is for prosodic reasons: "I've a car" has no word you can stress, other than "car", so people tend to change it to either "I have a car" or "I've got a car".

The other case is different: I can't think of any examples where I would expect to find "he's a pen", though I would rate it as perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Again, as part of a larger construction, '... he's a pen that cost over 300 pounds' would be acceptable colloquially in the UK. These contractions wouldn't be used in sentence- or sentence-fragment-terminal position.

Comment: With regard to your second para, what is the reason why a sentence's not possessing a word you can stress lead to people not finding it OK (and so, changing it)?

Comment: @MrReality: Dunno. I noticed that _I have a car_, _I've got a car_ and _I've a car in the garage_ are all OK, but _I've a car_ much less so, deduced that this was a prosodic issue, and speculated as to what the governing factor might be. Actually I've just realised that the short form can be natural in some contexts, eg answering a question: "Have you got anything in your pocket?" "I've a pen".

Comment: I found a really amazing explanation for this [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126774/shortest-correct-sentence-in-english-use-of-contractions), which says every clause in English has a mandatory stress slot in the predicate (though that raises another question, why is that so) and that stressed syllables cannot be syncopated; so if the reason it's awkward in AmE does have to do with stress & prosody, that oughta be it. But I'm confused why you say that "I've a car" has no words we can stress: Why can't we stress *car*, like we do *pen* in "I've a pen", in a similar context?

Answer (score 4):

They are both strictly correct but both slightly inelegant. The third especially could be confused with "He ***is*** a pen"

Some people like to avoid contractions like that in formal writing, but most people probably won't mind (or even notice).

It's probably wise to favour the contraction if you want to emphasise another part of the sentence: "I've *never* been so insulted!"

Comment: I'd go further and say that "He's a pen" is ALWAYS interpreted as "He IS a pen".

Answer (score 3):

"I've" seems fairly normal to me as British (or at least Scottish) English, and is completely unambiguous.  I don't think this "he's" would ever be understood as "he has" rather than "he is".

Answer (score 2):

It is rarely appropriate to use contractions in a formal writing environment.

I've heard the first construction in speech, mainly British English, but not the second.

Comment: As demonstrated in your second sentence!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there's nothing wrong with it, although Uncle Mikey is correct that it's rarely appropriate to use contractions in formal writing.

The only reason the second one seems strange is because most people would say "They're having a great time," I suppose because they're in the middle of having it. I have said, though, "I'd a great time..." I just happen to speak too quickly.:)

I also say "I've got..." rather than "I have." When I'm not speaking incorrectly, I generally just say "I've." So, it's not just a British thing.

Comment: Any chance of an explanation. I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with my answer, and I'd like to.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess is that someone disagrees with your claim that "there's nothing wrong with it".

Comment: That might just be it! Probably should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

(I've) is a fine contraction, just in American English you can only use it to replace (I have) when 'have' is used as an auxiliary verb (eg: In conjunction with a past participle).

I've been there. (Correct)
I've a dog. (Incorrect)

When the verb 'have' isn't auxiliary, It can't be contracted with pronouns.