# How is y’all’dn’t’ve pronounced

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, contractions, consonants, silent-letters

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_English_contractions), *y’all’dn’t’ve* is a valid contraction.

I am having difficulty pronouncing the *L-D-N-T-V* consonant cluster, especially since there is no vowel at the end (silent E). Y’all’dn’t’ve any advice or audio samples would you?

Comment: I've never heard "y’all’dn’t’ve" bundled up in a single word. To my mind, the most collapsed form of the wording that a person might actually say is "y’all wouldn’t’ve."

Comment: I call shenanigans. This is horse twaddle. People can put _anything_ in wikipedia, but it don't make it true. That is not a legitimate contraction. No sane Southener would contract the 'would' in that context. The smallest it'd get'd be "y'all wudnv".

Comment: @Mitch: I like the short form you gave better than the one I did because the t (and of course the l) in "wouldn't" often drops out. "Yall woodnuh" might work, too.

Comment: I've heard **y'all'd've** many times but never **y’all’dn’t’ve**.

Comment: @TimRomano I suppose that's pronounced *yawdove*?

Comment: @Nᴮᶻ: more or less, depending on twangitude. yallduv,  yeallduv.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50/can-a-word-be-contracted-twice-e-g-ivent/3267#3267

Comment: I'm skeptical too; this seems like at least two words.  I don't get the logic of the contraction between 'all' and 'would'.  All'd?

Comment: @kbelder *y'all* is a pronoun that for etymological reasons has an apostrophe. You're not contacting all + would, you're contacting y'all + would. And that's super common in speech: "y'all'd do it too if y'all had the chance"

Comment: @Mitch I'm pretty sure I'm a very sane (at least so make shrink tells me so) Southerner. What makes you think we wouldn't contract?

Comment: Related: [Is “I'd've” proper use of the English language?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/689/is-idve-proper-use-of-the-english-language)

Comment: So "you all do not have", or "you all did not have" contracts to Y'all'dn't've.  I would pronounce this as yawl-dunt-av

Comment: is <’dn’t’ve> only used with the pronon "y'all"?

Comment: @TRomano Link to a video of someone actually using these contractions? As a native english speaker I'm 99% sure that if someone tried this on me, my reaction would be: "say what?"

Comment: `yawl-dint-tive` - that's how IMO.

Comment: @Jono2906 Source?

Comment: FWIW, I would contract it as *y’all'd'na*, pronounced /'jɑld(ə)nə/ (c.f. *woulda* /wʊdə/), but I'm a Maritimer so *y'all* is a loanword to me ;)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I'd say this contraction of "you all would not have" as three syllables: [ˈjɔːɫ.ᵈn̩.tɘ̆v].

1. `[ˈjɔːɫ]` is *y'all*, a contraction of *you all* that serves as the plural of *you* in Dixie-influenced dialects of American English. The `l` with a tilde represents a ["dark" l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_lateral_approximants#Velarized_alveolar_lateral_approximant), which I realize with [pharyngealization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharyngealization) (secondary constriction in the throat) and some other speakers may realize with velarization.
2. `[ᵈn̩]` denotes a [pre-stopped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-stopped_consonant) nasal, as in the Russian names Dnieper and Dniester. The tick mark below the `n` denotes a  [syllabic consonant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant). It is the same as the last syllable of *redden*.
3. `[tɘ̆v]` has a slightly [raised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_vowel) schwa in the middle, roughly like the last syllable of *infinitive* except not quite as fronted. The cup-shaped breve mark over the vowel marks it as [extra-short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra-short).

Comment: This is almost how I (native Alabamian) would pronounce it in slow(ish) speech but I generally voice the t in t've. In fast, it'd be the same, but the final schwa vowel would be longer and the syllable would be open.

Comment: ...not sure about `[ᵈn̩]` .  I think this is further back - lateral release, maybe even a light `ɤ` leading into it.

Comment: Upvote for IPA, an actual pronunciation guide.

Answer (score 73):

As an American Southerner, I had a good laugh when I read this.

Depending on where you're from, this could either be incredibly easy or nigh impossible to pronounce.

Look at the words 'didn't' and 'hadn't,' first of all. In a Southern U.S. dialect especially, the 'd' in the middle of these words is *soft,* unlike the initial hard consonant of 'don't' or 'drive,' much like 'fiddle' (meaning violin in a bluegrass context) in the same dialect.

*Y'all* is actually spoken more like 'yaw' as in *yawn*.

The *'ve* is essentially 'of,' pronounced the same as the first syllable in *oven*. In context, it would very likely be pronounced as a simple 'uh,' similar to 'woulda, coulda, shoulda.'

So in the end, you get something like 'yawna' or 'yawdna.' This isn't *exactly* correct, but it's quite close.

Again, if you are a Northerner, Midwesterner, Canadian, Australian, or British, this may still not adequately explain how to pronounce this contraction.

I would suggest listening to someone like Jeff Foxworthy or Larry the Cable Guy speak for awhile. Then, you should have an easier time imagining how this is pronounced.

Comment: So something like *yawntove*...?

Comment: Yep, something almost exactly like that.

Used in a sentence: "If y'all'dn't've shut them barn doors, we could've run them pigs right yonder in!!"

Comment: @AdamHayes: The Deep South accent in my head reads that as “If yawna shut them bawn dowas, we coulda run them pigs raht yawnder iyun.” Accurate?

Comment: That's exactly it. "Yawna" or "yawdna." Some minor differences in your other words ('Bawurn dohwers' and 'rahtchyunder' are more accurate), but yeah. Sounds like something my dad would actually say.

Comment: Seems to me (as an East Alabama native) that this is the new negative past subjunctive clitic *'dna'; but in any context where this might appear the modal has to be stressed, so the vowel has to be represented: "If y'aladna dropped all em pices we woulda whupteir ice."

Comment: @AdamHayes wouldn't "y'all'dn't" be more correct in that sentence? Expanding to "if you all had not shut them barn doors..."

Comment: Nope. In redneck language, there's an extra 'have.' "If you all had not have..." = "If y'all'dn't've..."

Comment: "like 'yaw' as in yawn." Or like 'yaw' as in [yaw](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yaw#Pronunciation).

Comment: so true about ya'll not having the LL's pronounced. I'm in Appalachia, and never hear it. They say it in movies a lot, especially if actor doing a laughably bad southern accent. Think they just read script literally

Comment: it bothers me more than it should've that you put single quotes (instead of double quotes) around words that have apostrophes.

Comment: In my part of Texas (Gulf Coast), we do pronounce the ll in y'all, although sometimes the ll gets pronounced with the next syllable, as in yaw-llain't. Also, we are in the wouldna, couldna, shouldna, fitna (as in "fixin' to", meaning "about to") area of the pronunciation map. And I've just noticed that I say "yahll" rather than "yawll".

Comment: Y'all isn't just Southern — it's part of African American Vernacular English in the North as well, and at least where I grew up, the L is distinctly pronounced.

Comment: As an Alabamian, I generally wouldn't use words like y’all’dn’t’ve or speak as strongly as in some of the comments above.  (I didn't even recognize the word until reading what Adam Hayes wrote; the closest I use or probably even hear is "y'all hadn't've".)  Locally we also pronounce the L sound.

Comment: But this just goes to show that different parts of the south have different accents and so on, and even in the same part of the south, you will also see a difference between different groups of people.  Unfortunately the media always tries to go straight for the single most rednecky group they can find and portray everybody else like that.

Comment: I second that. I'm a Tennessee native, and I can honestly say we have a good variety of different types of people / accents here. But when people think of Tennessee, the FIRST thing that comes to mind is the worst, most racist, fundamentally religious, incestuous, and zoophilic hillbillies, and when asked to impersonate a Tennessee accent, THAT's the one most people use as an example.

Comment: [How to do a Southern Accent](http://www.howcast.com/videos/500509-how-to-do-a-mississippi-southern-accent-accent-training/)

Comment: Good luck with that ^

Comment: In Georgia we tend to make a point of pronouncing the Ls in *y'all* (due to that classic drawl) rather than sawing "yaw". That would be someone with a *very* country accent, not particularly a Southern accent. So *yawntove* is close, but I'd posit *`y'all ud'nt of`*.

Answer (score 23):

I think most native English speakers would have similar troubles. I wouldn't worry too much about it. Also, different people will say this different ways: somebody from Virginia (like me) will say it differently from somebody from Mississippi, who will say it differently from somebody from Texas.

But if you're curious, I'd start with the words that it's contracting:

- "You all would not have" shortens to "Y'all wouldn't have"
- "Y'all wouldn't have" shortens to "Y'all wouldn't've" - practice saying that out loud a few times.
- "Y'all wouldn't've" finally gets shortened to "y’all’dn’t’ve" - it's like what you were just practicing, just without the "woul" part.

Another way to look at it:

- Start with "would not have" and shorten that to "wouldn't've"
- Take out the W and shorten it to sound like "ooldn't've"
- Change the "ool" sound into an "all" sound: "all'dn't've"
- Add a "y" sound at the beginning: "y'all'dn't've"

In other words, you're having trouble with the L-D-N-T-V part because you need the Y-A part, or at least the A part, before the L sound to really blend the sounds together.

Phonetically, I'd pronounce it **yalldintuv**. But realistically, I don't know anybody who would say this in real life.

Answer (score 21):

In the South the phrase "Y'all would not have . . . " would most commonly be pronounced "Yaw woot nuh" with woot rhyming with foot. "Y'all would not have done that" = "Yaw woot nuh dun nat."

Answer (score 8):

If the uncontracted expression starts as "you all would not have ..." the natural progression would be

- "y'all woudn't have" /jal wødnt hæv/ (with syllabic 'n'). This is exceedingly formal.
- "y'all woudn't of" /jal wødntuv/. The 'd' is more like a alveolar flap (like the American 't' in 'writer')
- "y'all woudn't've" /jal wødnəv/.
- "y'all woudna" /jal wødnə/. This is the most...relaxed/informal, and probably the pronunciation you should be looking for.

In the end, the 'y'all' isn't smushed into the rest. It's a separately enunciated word.

As to Wikipedia, the entries are not necessarily accurate representations of reality. Wikipedia, as good as it *can* be, at any one time can have difficulties which may or may not be corrected for.

Comment: Alabamian here. I can imagine (after listening to myself try a few times) rural neighbors vocalizing the sentiment behind the contraction in question as /jaødnə/ or /jaøtnə/, definitely smushing the y’all into the rest with the /l/ and /w/ sounds disappearing into a shallow gulp.

Comment: @Greg I'm from Virginia. I can see that, but I also naturally pronounce "I don't know" as "ah unhuh" but with less articulation than is implied by using letters to represent the sounds.

Comment: You can very easily get it down to /jaldnə/ in actual speech. I'm not sure why you think the y'all needs to be separately enunciated, it may or may not depending on the actual sentence and its context.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find this expression in any other dictionary, but the actual phrase that was contracted would go through these steps:

You all did not have

Y'all did not have

Y'all didn't have

Y'all didn't've

It would sound like, "Yawl dintuv," which is quite a bit shorter than "You all did not have."  I did not keep the /d/ in didn't've because if the person is contracting this much already, they probably would say, "dint've."  If you did want to keep the /d/ it would be pronounced,
"didn'tuv."

I hope this helps y'all!

Comment: The start of the contraction is "you all **would** not have", not "you all **did** not have".

Answer (score 3):

IMO, this isn't Southern. This is *country*!

I think the phonetic spelling would be y'all-ood'nd've, where the "dn’t" is almost swallowed. Since it's a contraction of "wouldn't", you'd still sort of pronounce the "ould", which sounds like "wood" without the "w". Then you just add a sort of extra "not" contraction, "n't" which sounds like the end of "and" but with no "a". So "nd". Then just add the "ve", from the end of "I've".

There's no hard T sound. I'm sure you know that in American English, the T often sounds like a D, so you shouldn't be trying to pronounce a hard T sound.

Comment: Your assertion about d-for-t pronunciation is generally accurate for southeast Texas, where I grew up; but I strongly suspect that, in the part of the South that John Wayland Bales (above) is from, the pronunciation is otherwise. There are many subregional variations in speech in the South (to say nothing of "U.S. rural" as a speech region), and it's a good idea to avoid any sweeping attribution of a particular pronunciation to the whole region.

Comment: It's pretty common for Ts to be pronounced like D's in all parts of the United States (as in "auto"). However, it's not true for all Ts in speech (as in "faculty" or "discounted"). Sometimes it's not pronounced at all ("network"). Whether you're from Maine or Texas is irrelevant. In the case of y’all’dn’t’ve, the T would sound like a D. In a similar phrase, "I wouldn't've" the T sounds like a D. Adding y'all to the front wouldn't change that.

Comment: This is exactly the right answer (based on my experience of living in Georgia for my entire life).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a southern-ebonics twist on the English language, and would be pronounced as "y'all done eve", which would imply *You all don't even*.

Answer (score -1):

Is it pronounced

> 'yawdintuv'

or `

> 'yawntuv'

Either way it's a pretty incredible descent from

> 'you all did not have'

which by the way is terrible grammar, better to just say

> 'you did not'

which could be contracted to

> 'yawdint'

Comment: It is `you all would not have` not `all did not`.

Comment: If I heard someone say "yawdintuv," I would think (at least initially) that they were using a contracted form of "you ought not have."

Comment: The original contraction was `y’all’dn’t’ve`, surely `you all would not have` would be `y’all’wn’t’ve`

Comment: I fail to see what "terrible grammar" is "you all did not have". That is a perfectly grammatical construction as is in all standard dialects of English that I know (notice that "we all" and "they all" are also just fine). "He would not have" is contracted as "he'dnt've" (and "he would have" is "he'd've), so I'm not sure you feel the contracted form of "would" would be just "w"

Comment: I guess it's acceptable American English grammar but it's certainly not acceptable English grammar ;)

Comment: You might want to check the British National Corpus. You'll find lots of examples of "we all", " you all", and "they all" in addition to sequences like "you would not have [past part.]" in formal registers

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `you would not have` but `we all` and `you all` are pleonasms