# Contracting "Should not have"

Tags: contractions, apostrophe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a word be contracted twice (e.g. "I'ven't")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50/can-a-word-be-contracted-twice-e-g-ivent)

What is the correct way to contract "should not have", if there is one? "Should have" becomes "should've", "should not" becomes "shouldn't". Is "shouldn't've correct? It seems very strange to have two apostrophes in one word, but it also seems incorrect to skip an apostrophe where letters are omitted.

Comment: see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50/can-a-word-be-contracted-twice-e-g-ivent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, the correct way is "shouldn't have".