# Is there a word/term for a "super-contraction"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, contractions

I am doing some informal research into dynamic speech and narrative generation, and I've been looking into some local colloquialism and having a little bit of difficultly classifying a set of them. I would call them "super-contractions" or "a contraction of contractions". But I'm curious if there is a better word/phrase that represents them.

For example:

**I am going to** tell him that!
**I'm going to** tell him that!
**I'm gonna'** tell him that!
**I'm'a** tell him that!
**Ima** tell him that!

Comment: 'I'm' and 'gonna' are separate contractions, so no word is necessary to describe the uninteresting fact that one follows the other. Do you have good evidence for the use of the last two?

Comment: I would be tempted to coin "grandcontraction", "great-grandcontraction", etc.

Comment: @BarrieEngland *Imma* is definitely used in some southern dialects in the US, as well as in AAVE. Give this a listen, if you care to: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2FR2HpUpz4

Comment: I'd like to go with *hypercontraction*, which is used to describe muscle contractions.

Comment: @BarrieEngland i've heard its usage in some regions in the american south, similar in usage to the colloquialism "y'all"

Comment: I've actually heard another intermediate step: between "I'm gonna" and "I'm'a", there's "Ahmina"  (or "I'm'na").

Comment: In that case, I wonder if we aren't moving beyond contractions into new vocabulary.

Comment: There are certainly [people who use the contraction](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Imma+go+eat) in [more than one form](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=I%27ma+go+eat)

Comment: @BarrieEngland I don't know if there's really a difference between "I'm'a" and "Ima" in speech; in writing, I use only "Ima" with this meaning - for example, in text messages. I sometimes hear it among friends or in conversations in AAVE (east coast USA). Some evidence for use by searching for phrases like "ima tell", or `site:twitter.com "ima go"`: *ima tell her not to come if she tired* for example.

Comment: @aediaλ: I'm not aware of it in British speech, but that's not to say it may not exist.

Comment: There are also similar contractions like *he'da* (he would have).

Comment: We seem to be talking about spelling instead of what people are saying. Eye dialect is not really very useful. The question is about regionalisms, and those are **spoken** and best described in some kind of [phonetic transcription](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf), at least. If one is really interested in research, that's the bare minimum; professional sociolinguists conduct systematic syntax surveys and pack sound spectrographs.

Comment: That said, you can find quite a lot of variation in an individual's speech among all of these variants. They're not necessarily local; they may have more to do with socioeconomic factors, the time of day, or the stress the speaker is under. Collectively they're known as [**Fast Speech Rules**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/itsraining.html) in linguistics. They are, to understate the matter, very complex. Sorry.

Comment: Regarding I'm'a/ima/[imma](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Imma), it's also in Wiktionary with a number of [citations](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Citations:Imma#English) for how it has been used in print, if you *are* interested in the eye dialect used. (They give /aɪmə/ as the pronunciation, with which I would agree.)

Comment: Related (not duplicate): http://english.stackexchange.com/q/50/11762

Comment: I know a 5yo who says *dwut?* instead of *do you know what?*

Comment: You would appropriately call them *cntxns*, nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was considering **evolutionary** or **progressive** or **intensive** contraction. However, these words have connotations of aiming for better, which does not seem to work in terms of contraction.

Then I would suggest **degenerative** contraction. I would also consider **iterative** or **recursive** contraction. These suggestions are far from being precise, but they might give you some inspiration.

**Edit**: Based on some wisdom from the comments, I would also call it **over-contraction**, since the contraction **Ima** or even **I'm'a** could make little sense to and confuse people.

Comment: +1 for *degenerative contraction*. It was in my mind to suggest that by the time he reached the last two, OP's "contractions" were really just degenerate forms. What's with this recent flurry of questions (often from non-native speakers) wanting to know how far they can take written contractions? Do they think it makes them sound more "fluent"?

Comment: I, at least for the time being, am going to go with over-contraction in the documentation. I think it aptly fits the concept I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "double contraction" which sounds more clear

Suffix-Prefix Double Contractions:
suffix-prefix double contractions are formed from two contractions where the suffix of one contraction is the prefix of the other:

> she + would + have = she'd + would've = she'd've

Prefix-Prefix Double Contractions:
prefix-prefix double contractions, are formed from two contractions that share a prefix:

> they + will + have = they'll + they've = they'll've

Peculiar Cases:
double contractions where one of the contractions isn't arrived at formulaically makes the double contraction peculiar:

> he will not = he'll not = he'lln't
>   he will not = he won't = he'on't

Answer (score 0):

Since double contractions are regularly and frequently used even in educated speech, English grammar should have a place for them!

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment, -1 for not (clearly) answering the question.