# How do I abbreviate "little" correctly?

Tags: adjectives, abbreviations, apostrophe

As I understand it, apostrophes are used to show where a letter/letters are missing (e.g. shouldn't-> should not, hadn't-> had not).

So when I abbreviate "little", is it correct to write:

> li'l'

(with an apostrophe at the end for the missing "e")

I believe it is usually written

> li'l

(without the apostrophe)

But if we're leaving out the last apostrophe, can we leave out the middle one too, to give us:

> lil

Comment: I'd be guided by Li'l Abner.

Comment: @Barrie: I'd be tempted to say that *Li'l Abner* is the archetypal usage - if you don't want the connotations thereof, don't use the abbreviation in the first place.

Comment: *Li'l Abner* must have happened much after *Li'l* happened.

Comment: Li'l Abner is related to Bre'r Rabbit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Abbreviation* is usually the practice of writing a shortened word to save space on paper, or effort on the part of the writer. For example I might write "instr." as an abbreviation for "instrumental", or "vb." as an abbreviation for "verb".

Some abbreviations do indeed contain apostrophes: "international" becomes "int'l".

It is not usually expected that people would pronounce these words out loud in their abbreviated forms.

*Contraction* is the practice of leaving out parts of phrases like "it is" and "they are", ending up with "it's" and "they're". This is a way of writing down the shortened phrases *as they are spoken*. The apostrophes do indeed stand in for missing parts of the words.

However there are some spoken phrases that are sometimes written as a single word, where you might expect to see two apostrophes. "Cannot" becomes "Ca'n't" - but by convention we ignore one apostrophe and write "Can't" - see [Can a word be contracted twice (e.g. "I'ven't")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50/can-a-word-be-contracted-twice-e-g-ivent)

You are asking to abbreviate the word "little". There isn't a standard way to do that in the sense of "abbreviate" I've defined above.

However, in some accents, the "tt" of "little" becomes a glottal stop, and many writers have chosen to depict that as "li'l". It is a good phonetic representation of the way the word is spoken, where the apostrophe represents the small pause, or the glottal stop as it is said.

Comment: (In answer to a comment that seems to have disappeared) Glottal stop *or small pause*. Sometimes very small indeed. I've never, either in real life or on TV/film, heard it pronounced such that it exactly rhymes with "Lil". The difference is often subtle, and I'm willing to entertain the idea of it being psychosomatic.