# "I have" = "I've". Is that always correct?

Tags: grammar

> **Duplicate:**
>   [Is it appropriate to use short form of “have” ('ve) when it means possession?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-it-appropriate-to-use-short-form-of-have-ve-when-it-means-possession)

I feel uncomfortable saying sentences like the following:

- "***I've*** a car" instead of "***I have*** a car"
- "***He's*** a pen" instead of "***He has*** a pen"
- etc

I ask this because I read something like that in a book.

Are they correct? and what is the rule?