# "We've" vs "We have"

Tags: differences

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is it appropriate to use short form of “have” ('ve) when it means possession?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-it-appropriate-to-use-short-form-of-have-ve-when-it-means-possession)
>   [Can you contract the main verb in a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7636/can-you-contract-the-main-verb-in-a-sentence)

Is `we've` equivalent to `we have`?

In some cases, they do seem to be correct, but sometimes they don't. Consider these 4 sentences.

```
We've got a problem here.
We have got a problem here.

We've a problem here.
We have a problem here.
```

Which of these are correct, and which are wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it appropriate to use short form of “have” ('ve) when it means possession?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8/) and [Can you contract the main verb in a sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7636/)

Comment: @RegDwight Thanks! I did some search on the site before posting, but I didn't know what terms to search for exactly.

Comment: The search doesn't really work for words such as "have". Entirely not your fault. What I can recommend instead is having a look at the ["faq" tab under "Questions"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq), or [googling using the "site:" operator](http://www.google.com/search?q=contracted+have+site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 7):

**We've** is simply a contraction of *we have*.  All your examples are correct grammatically, it's just that some sound better than others.

Answer (score 7):

British English finds it generally acceptable to contract away the main verb of the sentence, for "We've a problem here."  American English does not like to do that, even though it is grammatically valid.