# [pronoun]'ve for possessives

Tags: possessives, perfect-aspect

My sister just wrote me, "I've a meeting a noon." The contraction "I've" stuck out. I've always thought the contraction was limited to the perfect tense, and do not recognize it as an indicator of possession.

Is the contraction [pronoun]'ve commonly accepted to mark possession?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

It is used for possession in this sense, but it's less common than "I've got" these days. "I've got" is very common, used as a simple possession marker rather than a perfect tense (i.e. equivalent to "I possess" without implying "I have obtained" as you'd expect from the construction).

On the other hand, it is still used and understood; consider the joke name "Ivor Biggun" (sounds like "I've a big 'un") - the joke wouldn't work unless "I've" is understood as a possession marker.

Comment: This is not quite right. [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/7658/300) is the actual answer.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I'm only speaking from a British English context; I really wouldn't know about American usage.

Comment: Of course, hence my comment.