# Is it correct: "We don’t have to go there if we don’t want to"?

Tags: grammar

Which sentences are correct?

> We don’t have to go there if we don’t want to.

or

> We haven’t to go there if we don’t want to.

Comment: The "unspecified/indefinite infinitive" is likely to be frowned upon in formal English, but colloquially it's fine.

Comment: Non-auxiliary *have* is not contracted in American English. Some related reading: [Is it appropriate to use short form of “have” ('ve) when it means possession?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8/) and [I'ven't a clue if this is possible. Can a word be contracted twice?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

American or British English, the correct way to phrase this idea is:

> We don't have to go there if we don't want to.

The other sentence

> We haven't to go there if we don't want to [Wrong]

as far as expressing this particular idea of not having to go somewhere, is incorrect. Why? When *have to/has to* is negated, the result is *don't have to/doesn't have to (do not have to/does not have to)*.

> - You have to do this / You *don't* have to do this
> - They have to go / They *don't* have to go
> - He has to be there / He *doesn't* have to be there

*haven't/hasn't* (*have not/has not*) is used to express a lack of something:

> - We haven't a clue.
> - We have not a single vote.
> - I haven't the faintest idea of his whereabouts.
> - She hasn't the slightest hint of the answer.

Comment: "British English, the correct way to phrase this idea is: _We don't have to go there if we don't want to._ " Doesn't BrE require a verb after _to_?

Comment: `I haven't got to go there` would also be correct, although likely rarer.

Comment: @adurdin: Sure, it would, but that's the direct negation of *have got to go there*, which I wasn't really considering...

Comment: @msh210: To the best of my knowledge, no.

Comment: Googling the Web for >"want to do then|if|because" site:.uk< gives a first-page estimate of 3,490,000 hits; >"want to then|if|because" site:.uk< gives 278,000, a 25:2 ratio. Same searches for .com give 78,200,000 and 7,720,000, respectively, a 20:2 ratio. So there may be _some_ support for my contention.

Answer (score 4):

In American English, at least, you would use the first construction:

> We don’t have to go there if we don’t want to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "correct" is not a very precise term in languages because they evolve constantly, and the definition of "correct" changes over time and depending on who you ask.

```
We don’t have to go there if we don’t want to.
```

This certainly sounds more natural than the other example. I would classify it as "nothing wrong with this one".

Comment: While I agree that languages evolve, I can't imagine any situation in the future where the second sentence will ever be correct.

Comment: @Elendil yeah but I couldn't say "the first one is correct" without such a remark...