# When is it acceptable to use "I've" by itself?

Tags: contractions

I have a friend from a foreign country who for years has used "I've" in a way that sounds funny to me. He often writes sentences like "I've an exam tomorrow." Is he correct in this usage?

I have always used "I've" but only when speaking in the past. For example: "I've never seen someone like that." Basically, I don't use "have" as the lone verb in the sentence. Thanks!

Comment: I'll not make this an answer, as I've not the sources to back it up, but in my experience as a native AmE speaker, that type of contraction seems British to me, or at least non-AmE. You'll find similar examples in the past tense and with "will," as I've noted. The usage is certainly correct; I believe it's just a dialectal preference, but that's only an observational guess.

Comment: Apparently this has already been asked: [Is it appropriate to use short form of "have" ('ve) when it means possession?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-it-appropriate-to-use-short-form-of-have-ve-when-it-means-possession?rq=1)

Comment: So you would never say "I've got ten dollars in my pocket"? (I know that's not grammatical (for different reasons than this question talks about), but it's common).

Comment: The title of your question is imprecise. What do you mean by "*I've* by itself"? "I've a new car", "I've an exam coming up" - it is not "by itself",  it sits in a sentence and certainly has words around it !!!

Comment: Actually, I say that all the time. I suppose that's because I consider "got" the main verb of the sentence, so the "have" doesn't carry much meaning. But if the "got" drops off, I usually say "I have" rather than "I've." Bear in mind that I _do_ sometimes contract "have" and "will" in the manner you've described, but most of the time I don't.

Comment: When someone asks, "Have you got a moment?" and you answer, "I've", then that is "by itself". And then only under such circumstances warrants a question about the oddness.

Comment: Also, and this is perhaps just tangential, but I recently noticed that all the dialogue in the videogame _Bravely Default_ for the Nintendo 3DS uses the contracted form, without exception, no matter the characters. Seems like the writer(s) for the game find that usage normal.

Comment: @BlessedGeek Yes, the title is imprecise, and could stand to be reworded, but the text of the question itself clarifies OP's intent nicely.

Comment: The situation you depict does not warrant a question on this forum. It surprises me that you would even ask a question for the situation you depict because I've been using "I've a car in the driveway", "I've a knife in my pocket", "I've an exam tomorrow". Which provincial corner/nutshell of the USA are you living in?

Comment: I assume you're addressing dimholte with your questions, @BlessedGeek?

Comment: @BlessedGeek: Are you aware that whole generations _in Europe_ have learned to use _got_ in every example sentence you just mentioned? Because according to our teachers, that was "correct English". There are also plenty of Americans who will use _got_ in those sentences, and leaving it out will sounds positively outlandish to many speakers, so I believe the question is certainly warranted, notwithstanding your specific usage.

Comment: "I've got ...." is colloquial/informal English. It is "correct" but not acceptable in formal technical manuals.

Comment: It is annoying that continental Europeans are developing their own pidgin English. e.g. mis-aligning gerunds and sorts, lay-outing instead of laying-out, passer-bys instead of passers-by. Do they even teach these as "valid English" in schools?