# Is it correct to shorten "you have" to "you've"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, contractions

If "you are" can be shortened to "you're", can "you have" be shortened to "you've"? Is it acceptable? If yes, what are the situations where it can be used?

Comment: Why do you think it might not be? What gave you that idea?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I suppose you can shorten *you have* to *you've.* The possible situations are as follows:

1. You've been to that place.
2. You've got to go there.
3. You've got a car.
4. You've a car.
5. You've to go there.

Comment: Actually, in many literary works "You've to go there" would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: And when transcribing dialog "You've a car?" would not be at all unusual.

Comment: I would distinguish between "formal writing" and "formal speaking" when talking about this issue. For example, many formal writing styles call for reduced or eliminated contractions. But in formal speaking contexts, there's no special reason to avoid contractions. "**I am** very pleased to meet you, Dr. Smith. **I have** read nearly all of your research papers." does not sound any more formal than "**I'm** very pleased to meet you... **I've** read nearly all of your research".

Comment: The reason you may not replace "You have a car" with "You've a car" has to do with what words you're emphasizing. If you emphasize **have** then the contraction doesn't make any sense (There's no way to emphasize "**'ve**"). On the other hand, if you're asking "You've a **car**??" then it would make sense when you hear it.

Comment: Thank you for correction Hot Licks and Brandin. I am still learing.

Comment: I came up with another situation: ''do you've a pen?'' I am not sure about this.

Comment: If "have" is used as a helping verb, it can be contracted. However, if it is the main verb, it should not. https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-classification-helping.htm

Comment: "You've a car" and "do you've a pen" are only grammatical in British English, but not in (Standard) American English. In American English, [*have* cannot be contracted when it's the main verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/3026/300).