# "'ve" contraction in Canadian and Australian English

Tags: formality, contractions, australian-english, canadian-english

I'm wondering if in Australian or Canadian English you can use " 've" before a noun phrase in informal style:

- I've a car.
- They've a great time.

The question is somewhat related to [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-it-appropriate-to-use-short-form-of-have-ve-when-it-means-possession?newreg=58f12a8ea84843abaaf70cc2ba5d83da). The thread there shows that you can say this in British English but not in American English. Yet no one mentions AusE or CanE there.

Comment: Hello, Khrystyna. What do you mean by 'also' here? I think that 'I've a car' for 'I have/possess a car' would be very rarely used in the States. It would be quite normal in conversations in the UK, but not as a stand-alone, where 'I've got a car.' is standard. 'I've a car that will do over 60 to the gallon, but I use the other one because it's a lot quicker.' / 'They've a great time.' sounds unnatural as a stand-alone, but 'They've a great time ahead of them.' is quite idiomatic in the UK.

Comment: Hi @EdwinAshworth! Thanks for the comment. By "also" I meant exactly British English as you mentioned. I will edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: In spoken AuE, the 'h' may be swallowed and words run together, but this doesn't normally translate to the written form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a Canadian in my sixties and have lived in three different regions of the country.  I've never heard "I've" as a contraction of "I have" in the sense of ownership.